# Camellia and ECDHE_ECDSA -ECDSA in TLS1.2

Tags: tls

I am setting up a server using nginx. I have it working with a self signed ecc certificate and if I connect it reports ECDHE-ECDSA which is what I wanted. But I was also wondering if I could use Camellia with this.

- [RFC 4492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492) specifies the ECC extensions.
- [RFC 5932](https://ietf.org/doc/rfc5932/?include_text=1) - specifies the Camellia Cipher Suites for TLS

but I can see no intersection between the two? Am I missing something or is this not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cipher suites you're looking for are defined in [RFC 6367](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6367), as listed in the [TLS Cipher Suite Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4). (To find them on the Registry page, scroll down to "0xC0,0x72" or "RFC6367".)

However, you have another problem: *OpenSSL doesn't support them.* If you really want to use them, you'll have to find a reverse proxy/SSL terminator/web server -- and client! -- that uses something like GnuTLS or PolarSSL.

(I hope someone will add support for modern Camellia cipher suites to OpenSSL, just because I think Camellia is neat, but I'm afraid that someone won't be me.)

By the way, if you meant *ephemeral* elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman, you meant "ECDH**E**-ECDSA". "ECDH-ECDSA" is actually a different thing -- also defined for Camellia in the above RFC -- which isn't ephemeral, and which people mostly never use.

---

In August 2014, support for the [eight HMAC-based cipher suites from RFC 6367](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6367#section-2.1) was [committed to OpenSSL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/750487899ad2b794078ed998b513a4a14f60f2cc). The GCM suites weren't added, but Camellia is now usable with ECC -- if you run OpenSSL from git, anyway. I don't know what release it will be in. (For all I know, the commit might be reverted tomorrow! In any case, it's progress.)

Comment: Thanks. I did mean ECDHE edited question to reflect that.